# Empty headers from admin-on-rest point of view

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm trying admin-on-rest for a new project, it seems interesting. I've been able to follow the tutorial with no issues.

Moving now on my custom test project I experience an issue with headers from AOR point of view: they are empty when I inspect them using Chrome or Safari debugger.

Putting a breakpoint in `jsonServer.js/convertHTTPResponseToREST` I can see that AOR correctly see the JSON content returned by my server, and a status code of 200. But when I look at the headers array, it's 100% empty, nothing visible.

However, if I look the same exchange from Wireshark point of view, headers are here (with `Content-Type` and `X-Total-Count`).

Server is written in Swift/Kitura, I've correctly setup the CORS options. And when I look at Wireshark trace, I correctly see the headers for the GET, and `Access-Control-Request-Headers:X-Total-Count` when AOR is requesting the OPTIONS.

Any idea of what should I look for?

What could lead AOR to not see headers seen by Wireshark?

Comment: I've worked on the issue a little bit, presenting the files from the same server solve the issue.

So, it's CORS related but I don't understand why since I correctly see the field in the HTTP stream.

Comment: Can you send us the details of the "OPTIONS" response, done just before the `GET` request?

Answer (score 4):

After some [(French) debugging on Twitter](https://twitter.com/ygini/status/948230898641768448), we found the issue. We have to add the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header, as explained in the error message in [source code](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/49a616c93d1ee5ea0bfa3c5f7abea0bb29c8d01c/src/rest/jsonServer.js#L100).

Comment: Indeed, Access-Control-Request-Headers lead me in confusion, you need both keys containing the same values to make it work.

Comment: Excepted that I can't ^^ I don't have any button for that and my upvote is flagged as not enough valuable because I've too low reputation score… (this and the rules about "no open questions" are part of the reason why I dislike SO as support platform)